# Google Sheets, For Loop to auto update stocks from google api

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

As the title describes I'm trying to update a stock price with a script.  I understand that this is likely trivial for most of you, but it's my first time scripting with google sheets.

From what I can see this code should be okay and the code within the loop does work on it's own.

It makes a list for for every time the list has a value it will process the command.  Currently the command will only repeat on the same row as I've not figured how to increment the row properly yet.

I want to read from column A and as long as there is a value to increment which A row is read to get the stock symbol, pull the value, and paste it in an incremented E row.

---

```
function getData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var symbol = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();  

    for (var row = 2, var count = symbol.length; row < count; row++) {      
        if (symbol[row] !=''){    
            ss.getRange('E2').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2)'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want. The issue with your script was that the E2 was hardcoded in, as was the A2 so it didn't iterate through as needed.

```
function getData() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var symbol = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();  

  for(i=0; i<symbol.length; i++)
  {
    if (symbol[i]!=""){
      ss.getRange('E'+(i+2)).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE(A'+(i+2)+')'); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This does indeed work. You've opened my eyes.  I'd like to give you a 1^, but my account is new.  Regardless, much appreciated Tom

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've gotten lots of help here. You can accept the answer if it works for you. Just click on the check mark. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I see, missed that step.  Next step, run it on multiple steps. I'll do some more research since this really should be a common loops hanging around out there.